# Flutter Syncfusion Calendar doesn't show data

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, flutter-dependencies, syncfusion-calendar

I have a problem with SyncFusion's flutter calendar which is demonstrated by this screenshot
[image]

As you see the calendar still get the data from my API but it doesn't show any meeting data on the calendar. FYI, I would like get the data with each time i click on each day, that why I'm using onViewChanged

Here is my full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/App/Config/palette.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/Icon/dbicons.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/Widgets/dialog_loading.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/giangvien/Screens/XemTKB/TKBTheoNgay/tkbngay_viewmodel.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/giangvien/models/meeting.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/giangvien/models/meetingdata_source.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';

class TKBNgay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TKBNgayState createState() => _TKBNgayState();
}

class _TKBNgayState extends State<TKBNgay> {
  DateTime date;

  List<DateTime> _blackoutDates = <DateTime>[];
  CalendarController _calendarController;
  CalendarController _onViewChanged;
  DateTime _chosenDate = DateTime.now();

  CalendarDataSource _calendarDataSource;
  dynamic scheduleViewBuilder;
  bool _showDatePickerButton = true;
  bool _allowViewNavigation = true;
  bool _showLeadingAndTrailingDates = true;
  DateTime _minDate;
  DateTime _maxDate;
  final List<CalendarView> _allowedViews = <CalendarView>[
    CalendarView.day,
    CalendarView.week,
    CalendarView.workWeek,
    CalendarView.month,
    CalendarView.schedule
  ];
  ViewChangedCallback viewChangedCallback;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<TKBNgayViewModel>.reactive(
        builder: (context, model, child) => SfCalendar(
              onViewChanged: (details) {
                List<DateTime> dates = details.visibleDates;
                model.getTkbNgay(dates[0]);
              },
              // onTap: (details) {
              //   DateTime date = details.date;
              //   model.getTkbNgay(date);
              // },
              controller: _calendarController,
              dataSource: MeetingDataSource(model.getDataSource),
              scheduleViewMonthHeaderBuilder: scheduleViewBuilder,
              // appointmentBuilder: appointmentBuilder,
              appointmentTimeTextFormat: 'hh:mm:ss a',
              initialDisplayDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year,
                  DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day, 00, 45, 0),
              allowedViews: _allowedViews,
              showDatePickerButton: _showDatePickerButton,
              allowViewNavigation: _allowViewNavigation,
              blackoutDates: _blackoutDates,
              minDate: _minDate,
              maxDate: _maxDate,
              monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
                  appointmentDisplayMode:
                      MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment,
                  showTrailingAndLeadingDates: _showLeadingAndTrailingDates,
                  appointmentDisplayCount: 4),
              // timeSlotViewSettings: const TimeSlotViewSettings(
              //     minimumAppointmentDuration: Duration(minutes: 60)),
              timeSlotViewSettings: TimeSlotViewSettings(
                startHour: 0,
                endHour: 16,
                timeFormat: " H",
                timeIntervalHeight: 60,
                timeTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              selectionDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 2),
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              ),
            ),
        viewModelBuilder: () => TKBNgayViewModel());
  }
}

void calendarTapped(CalendarTapDetails details) {
  if (details.targetElement == CalendarElement.viewHeader) {}
}

Widget appointmentBuilder(BuildContext context,
    CalendarAppointmentDetails calendarAppointmentDetails) {
  final Meeting appointment = calendarAppointmentDetails.appointments.first;
  return Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: calendarAppointmentDetails.bounds.width,
        height: calendarAppointmentDetails.bounds.height,
        // color: appointment.background,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 0.25,
          ),
          color: appointment.background,
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              '${appointment.tkb.maMonHoc} - ${appointment.tkb.tenMonHoc}',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Palette.kSecondColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Phòng: ${appointment.tkb.maPhongHoc} - Nhóm MH: ${appointment.tkb.nhom}',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Palette.kSecondColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Giảng viên: ${appointment.tkb.giaoVien}',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Palette.kSecondColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Here is my viewmodel code :

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/giangvien/models/meeting.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/giangvien/models/thoikhoabieu_ngay.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/giangvien/services/schedule.service.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

class TKBNgayViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  List<ThoiKhoaBieuNgay> _tkbNgayModels;
  List<ThoiKhoaBieuNgay> get tkbNgayModels => _tkbNgayModels ?? [];
  List<Meeting> _getDataSource = [];

  ScheduleService _scheduleService = new ScheduleService();
  List<Meeting> get getDataSource => _getDataSource;

  CalendarController calendarController = CalendarController();
  DateFormat formatDateTitle = DateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy", 'vi');
  String _currentTime = DateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy", 'vi').format(DateTime.now());
  DateTime _timeSelect = DateTime.now();
  DateTime get timeSelect => _timeSelect;

  String get currentTime => _currentTime;
  DateTime timeNow = DateTime.now();
  DateFormat date = new DateFormat('dd/MM/y');
  int day = DateTime.now().day;

  getTkbNgay(DateTime dateTime) async {
    _currentTime = formatDateTitle.format(dateTime);
    _timeSelect = dateTime;


    String today = date.format(dateTime);
    var day = today.split("/");
    if (day[0].length < 2) return day[0] = '0${day[0]}';

    String dateParse = '${day[0]}/${day[1]}/${day[2]}';

    List<ThoiKhoaBieuNgay> getTKBNgay =
        await _scheduleService.getThoiKhoaBieuNgay(dateParse, true);

    _getDataSource.clear();
    if (getTKBNgay != null) {
      DateTime _startTime = timeNow;
      DateTime _endTime = timeNow;
      getTKBNgay.forEach((element) {
        _startTime = DateTime(timeNow.year, timeNow.month, timeNow.day,
            element.tietBatDau.toInt(), 0, 0);
        _endTime = _startTime.add(Duration(hours: element.soTiet.toInt()));
        _getDataSource.add(Meeting(
          eventName: element.tenMonHoc,
          from: _startTime,
          to: _endTime,
          subText: element.maPhongHoc,
          tkb: element,
          background: Color(0xFFFEFEA5),
        ));
      });
    } else {
      getTKBNgay = [];
    }

    _tkbNgayModels = getTKBNgay.toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Comparator<ThoiKhoaBieuNgay> priceComparator =
      (a, b) => a.tietBatDau.compareTo(b.tietBatDau);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Getting the visible date appointment details:**
You can get the appointment of the visible date details by using the **getVisibleAppointments** helper method of the Calendar data source. Please find the pub documentation link for the same.

**Pub documentation link:** https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_calendar/latest/calendar/CalendarDataSource/getVisibleAppointments.html

Also, we have a KB document for showing the visible dates appointments in an alert window. Please find the KB document from the following link.

**KB link:**
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12549/how-to-get-the-appointments-between-the-given-start-and-end-date-in-the-flutter-calendar

Also please find some helper methods of data source from the following UG documentation.

**UG link:**
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/appointments#appointment-helper

We hope that this helps you. Please let us know if you need further assistance.